# bash concat strings in single variable using while read

Tags: mysql, database, bash, shell

In the following script, I try to get all tables name from a mysql database and I expect all table's name printed out, but no matter what I do or which [method](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) I use, it just doesn't work. the printed string I suppose are tables name overlapped on each other:

> watchdoglescabularyrchygsey

What's wrong with this script?

```
  mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE |
    { 
    while read table
    do
    alltables="$alltables $table"
    done 
    echo $alltables;
    }
```

Comment: `mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE | xargs`

Comment: What is the output of the `mysql` command by itself? That said, always use `IFS= read -r table` unless you have a compelling reason not to. You might also want to check the output of `echo "$alltables" | od` to get a better idea of exactly what characters are in the value.

Comment: the output is tables name connected with \n\r, and that was the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that `mysql` separates the table names by `\n\r` instead of `\n`? The `read` would then read `First Table`, `\rSecond Table`, and so on. In most linux terminals `\r` causes the cursor to jump back to the start of the current line. `ABC\r_` will be printed as `_BC`.

#### Checking for `\r`

Execute `mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE | sed 's:\r:\\r:'` and look at the output. The control character `\r` will be printed as the literal string `\r`.

#### Deleting the `\r`

Insert a `... | tr -d '\r' | ...` between the commands.

Comment: the checking snippet didn't display \r, but it worked, thank you. :)